# populating screen scraped info into a list

Tags: android, eclipse, listview, screen-scraping, listadapter

I want to populate a screen scraped info from a website into a custom list, I have parsed the data using jsoup from this website:

www.soccerway.com

but i cant launch my app it causes a runtime exception here are the code and the error trace:

```
public class ScoresActivity extends ListActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.scoresactivity);

    setListAdapter(new MyAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, R.id.textViewhometeam,
               getResources().getStringArray(R.array.pls)));

    final ListView lv = getListView();
    lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
         public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                  // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
                    //int pos = lv.getSelectedItemPosition();
                  //if(pos == 0){
                      //Intent intent = new Intent(Legends.this, l1.class);
                      //startActivity(intent);
                  //}

         }
    });

}

public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

    public MyAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId,
            String[] strings) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, strings);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item3, parent, false);

        //String[] items = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.legends);

        TextView tv1 = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textViewhometeam);
        TextView tv2 = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textViewfinalscore);
        TextView tv3 = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textViewawayteam);

        Document doc;
        try {
            doc = (Document) Jsoup.connect("http://www.soccerway.com/teams/saudi-arabia/al-nasr-riyadh/matches/").get();
            Elements team_a = ((Element) doc).select("td.team-a");
            for (Element e : team_a) {
                CharSequence ta = e.text();
                tv1.setText(ta);
                //System.out.println("team a is: " + ta);
            }

            Elements team_b = ((Element) doc).select("td.team-b");
            for (Element e : team_b) {
                CharSequence tb = e.text();
                tv3.setText(tb);
                //System.out.println("team b is: " + tb);
            }

            Elements result = ((Element) doc).select("td.score");
            for (Element e : result) {
                CharSequence re = e.text();
                tv2.setText(re);
                //System.out.println("score is: " + re);
            }
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }




        return row;

    }


}
```

}

scoresactivity.xml is simply a listview
list_item3.xml is my custom list it simply contains 3 text view for the home team, away team and the score.

here is the error:

```
11-09 02:33:24.379: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(325): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-09 02:33:24.379: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(325): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to      start activity ComponentInfo{com.nassr.alnassrfc/com.nassr.alnassrfc.Main}:   java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a TabHost whose id attribute is   'android.R.id.tabhost'
11-09 02:33:24.379: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(325):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
11-09 02:33:24.379: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(325):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
11-09 02:33:24.379: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(325):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
11-09 02:33:24.379: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(325):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
11-09 02:33:24.379: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(325):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-09 02:33:24.379: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(325):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-09 02:33:24.379: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(325):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
11-09 02:33:24.379: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(325):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-09 02:33:24.379: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(325):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
11-09 02:33:24.379: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(325):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
11-09 02:33:24.379: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(325):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
11-09 02:33:24.379: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(325):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-09 02:33:24.379: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(325): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a TabHost whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.tabhost'
11-09 02:33:24.379: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(325):     at android.app.TabActivity.onContentChanged(TabActivity.java:105)
11-09 02:33:24.379: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(325):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:201)
11-09 02:33:24.379: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(325):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1647)
11-09 02:33:24.379: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(325):     at com.nassr.alnassrfc.Main.onCreate(Main.java:19)
11-09 02:33:24.379: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(325):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
11-09 02:33:24.379: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(325):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
11-09 02:33:24.379: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(325):     ... 11 more
11-09 02:33:24.399: WARN/ActivityManager(59):   Force finishing activity com.nassr.alnassrfc/.Main
11-09 02:33:24.899: WARN/ActivityManager(59): Activity pause timeout for HistoryRecord{45073020 com.nassr.alnassrfc/.Main}
11-09 02:33:26.921: WARN/InputManagerService(59): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@450773b8
```

Here is my Main class extending TabActivity and using TabHost

```
public class Main extends TabActivity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.custome_title);

    Resources res = getResources();
    TabHost tabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost); 
    TabHost.TabSpec spec;  
    Intent intent;  // Reusable Intent for each tab
    tabHost.getTabWidget();


    // Create an Intent to launch an Activity for the tab (to be reused)
    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, ClubActivity.class);

    // Initialize a TabSpec for each tab and add it to the TabHost
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("club").setIndicator("",
                      res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_alnassr))
                  .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    // Do the same for the other tabs
    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, ScoresActivity.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("scores").setIndicator("",
                      res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_alnassr1))
                  .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, TableActivity.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("table").setIndicator("",
                      res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_alnassr2))
                  .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

 // Create an Intent to launch an Activity for the tab (to be reused)
    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, MessageList.class);

    // Initialize a TabSpec for each tab and add it to the TabHost
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("News").setIndicator("",
                      res.getDrawable(android.R.drawable.star_on))
                  .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, YoutubeActivity.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("youtube").setIndicator("",
                      res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_alnassr3))
                  .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
}
```

}
thanks guys.

Answer (score 1):

It is pretty clear from the log that your activity com.nassr.alnassrfc.Main can't load because it was expecting android.R.id.tabhost for a tabhost. I would check your layout and activity of  com.nassr.alnassrfc.Main. Does that activity extend tabhost, if it does why is there no tabhost in the layout?

I don't think the code you posted is related to the bug.

Comment: Hi sgarman, my main works fine if i delete all the code related to the scoresactivity(and it's a tab by the way), but when the code above is used in the scoresactivity the whole program doesn't run causing a runtime error. So basically the error is in the code above.Regarding your question about main activity it doesn't extend tabhost, it extends tabactivity...hope this helps :)

Comment: That is flawed logic, regardless, If your extending TabActivity you need to have a <TabHost> see: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html for use with tabs. Without seeing your tabactivity and layout it is hard to see what the issue is. I'm not even sure how you are launching this activity.

Comment: check above to see my main activity